# Android: Lint says - Class referenced in the layout file, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, lint

In my app, I am using [Pull TO Refresh list view](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library. I had designed layouts for all screens respectively. When I ran lint on my project, in one of my layout file for xlarge screen, it gave me fatal error:

> Class referenced in the layout file,
>   com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView, was not
>   found in the   project or the libraries

While in same layout file for other screens, it is giving no error at all. Also, I had used same library in other layouts of my file, where it does not give any error. It is giving same error for `Google Maps` api as well. My project targets Google Api level 16 and I had checked, all libraries are added to it. But,the error doesn't go away even on cleaning project.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve it? I've found someone reported it as an issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=48310 but there is no answer how to fix it (or will it be fixed in Lint).

Comment: Not yet, looking for some resource. Thanks for the link. I will read it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a lint bug and you can safely ignore it. Lint is meant to help, not to hinder your development time. Change the lint Errors to warnings and you can compile and run the app just fine. I don't recommend turning it off because it helps to keep your code cleaner.

Comment: Here is the issue on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40005 It says that the fix will be released in ADT 22.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński well i have ADT 22, and it became even worse. now the ADT also can't show any custom view, while it could do it before.

Answer (score 0):

Make a project `Project -> Clean...` this resets the bug errors for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a similar error, for me, it was resolved by adding `android.enableJetifier=true` to **gradle.properties**.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the lint error by, passing the error type to the ignore attribute within that view, for example:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    ...
    tools:ignore="MissingClass"
    ...
/>
```

Just make sure you have tools imported:

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

References:

https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/MissingClass.md.html

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when i changed thé android studio IDE, To solve it:
-reate a new project;
-replace the content of dependencies in build.gradle of your project with the content of dependencies in build.gradle of the new project;
-sync project with gradle.
And it will work.